# DocumentDB IQueryable "AsSQL" error

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I'm currently trying to make use of DocumentDB's SQL parameterization support via `SqlQuerySpec`. The overloaded method I am invoking is:

`IQueryable<T> IReliableReadDocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(Uri documentsUri, SqlQuerySpec querySpec, [FeedOptions feedOptions = null], [object partitionKey = null]) where T: DocumentBase, new ()`

The issue is that every time I try to execute the query by enumerating it via `ToList()` or the generic `AsEnumerable()`, I get this error thrown:

`Method "AsSQL" is not supported. Only LINQ methods are supported.`

I'm assuming that it's taking issue with the `SqlQuerySpec` parameter, as this works fine using the overload that takes a `string sqlExpression`, but that doesn't nicely support parameters. Creating the document query doesn't error; it's thrown whenever I try to execute it by enumerating it. If anyone could give me any insight into this error, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have this issue too, and cant seem to find the solution. I'm amazed how BAD Cosmos Db querying is... facepalm!

Did you find a solution?

Comment: I dont know if this will help you, I had the same error message "Method 'AsSQL' is not supported. Only LINQ Methods are supported." when getting the count on the object returned by "client.CreateDocumentQuery(collLink, queryText2, options);"

Solution was to appand ".ToList()" at the end of "client.CreateDocumentQuery(collLink, queryText2, options);" then its a list object of some type.